# Download the file from the server or output an error if there is one

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax

I have something like this Python code:

```
with open('test.bin', 'rb') as file:
    file_content = file.read()
    response = HttpResponse(file_content, 
    content_type='application/octet-stream')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'attachment;filename=test.bin'
    return response
```

There may not be a file, so you should return an error somewhere, but how to do it so that it can be read on Ajax and output to the user.

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'test',
        type: 'GET',
        headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': getCookie('csrftoken'), },
        xhrFields: {
        'responseType': 'blob'
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                var contentDisposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                var matches = /filename=([^;]+)/ig.exec(contentDisposition);
                var fileName = (matches[1] || 'untitled').trim();

                var blob = new Blob([data], {type: xhr.getResponseHeader('Content-Type')});
                var link = document.createElement('a');
                link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                link.download = fileName;
                link.click();
        },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        },
});
```

But the fact is that because of the xhrFields field, the data is perceived as a blob, so in xhr.responseText(type string) I get [object Blob]

How do I get the file downloaded and the error output in case of an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then you have 3 options

1. Raise exception on the server and handle 'error' property in JQuery.
2. Make 2 views, one validates the response and either return an error or a link to the view to download the file/
3. make the view return a JSON for example in case of err
   `{"error": "file doesn't exist"}` and in case of success return `{"file":FILE_BINARY_DATA}`